# Format GridView column based on value in other column

Tags: gridview, format

I have a gridview like this:

```
flag                 number
2013                 2315
2013                 25986
YYT Tredn (%)        2
YYT Tredn (%)        3
```

I want to format the numbers based on the value in flag column, like row with flag 2013 to format with comma and with YYY Trend (%) with % something like this:

```
flag                 number
2013                 2,315
2013                 25,986
YYT Tredn (%)        2%
YYT Tredn (%)        3%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **may** be a little overkill, but this is how I would accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
    protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Row.Cells[0].Text)
        {
            case "2013":
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = FormatNumberWithComma(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
                break;
            case "YYT Tredn (%)":
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = FormatNumberWithPercent(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
                break;
        }
    }

    private string FormatNumberWithPercent(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = int.Parse(input);
            return String.Format("{0}%", result);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "NaN";
        }
    }

    private string FormatNumberWithComma(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = int.Parse(input);
            return String.Format("{0:#,###0}", result);
        }
        catch
        {
            return "NaN";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nnurvx, excellent solution, just had to change formatting on the formatnumberwithcomm with return String.Format("{0:0,000}", result);

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for the incorrect format, I have updated my answer to reflect the correct format for the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the value in the [OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.  There is an example of how to do this in the link i provided.